# Resend message to other service bus from Azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure function where I want to get the messages from a Service bus Subscription on a Topic, and then resend all the message to another service bus

But when I try this I get all kind of exception and it never gets any of the messages send to the other service bus.

Here is how I do it in my azure function

```
public PartStatusFunction(ILogger<PartStatusFunction> log, IEnvironmentVariableLoader environmentVariableLoader)
    {
        _logger = log;
        _environmentVariableLoader = environmentVariableLoader;
    }

    [FunctionName("PartStatusFunction")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("partstatus", "linktestest", Connection = "smartadmin.messagebus.subscription.name")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {message}");

        try
        {
            ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender = _environmentVariableLoader.GetServiceBusClient().CreateSender("partstatus");
            ServiceBusMessage serviceMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(message);
            await serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Failed to send message to linktest azure bus: " + message.ToString() + " Exception " + e.ToString());

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I have created an EnvironmentVariableLoader class that is created in a singleton instance on my startup class

```
 public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEnvironmentVariableLoader, EnvironmentVariableLoader>();   
    }
}
```

The EnvironmentVariableLoader then creates a the ServiceBusClient like this

```
private ServiceBusClient _serviceBusClient;

    public EnvironmentVariableLoader()
    {
        _serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient("Endpoint=xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            new ServiceBusClientOptions()
            {
                TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp, 
            });
    }

    public ServiceBusClient GetServiceBusClient()
    {
        return _serviceBusClient;
    }
```

When I try to do this in a console application it works.

```
 _serviceBusClientReceive = new ServiceBusClient("Endpoint=yyyyyyyyy",
            new ServiceBusClientOptions()
            {
                TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp
            });

        _serviceBusClientSend = new ServiceBusClient("Endpoint=xxxxxxxx",
            new ServiceBusClientOptions()
            {
                TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpTcp
            });

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var serviceBusReceiver = _serviceBusClientReceive.CreateReceiver("partstatus", "linktestest");
                var receivedMessage= await serviceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();
                
                ServiceBusSender serviceBusSender = _serviceBusClientSend.CreateSender("partstatus");
                ServiceBusMessage serviceMessage = new ServiceBusMessage(receivedMessage);
                await serviceBusSender.SendMessageAsync(serviceMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                
            }
        }
```

Is it not possible to create a connection to another service bus in an Azure Function?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you're not using and output binding to send the message to the destination queue? It could simplify your code.

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: I'll provide an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Azure Functions, the solution could be significantly simpler than the original suggestion if you use an Azure Service Bus output binding to complement the trigger. In essence, your Functions code becomes a bridge between the incoming queue and the outgoing queue.

```
public class Functions
{
    private readonly ILogger<Functions> logger;

    public Functions(ILogger<Functions> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    [ServiceBusAccount("ServiceBusConnection")]
    [FunctionName(nameof(PartStatusFunction))]
    [return: ServiceBus("%OutputQueue%")]
    public Task<ServiceBusMessage> PartStatusFunction([ServiceBusTrigger("%InputQueue%")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Sending message with ID {MessageId} to the destination queue", message.MessageId);

        return Task.FromResult(new ServiceBusMessage(message));
    }
}
```

The configuration would require values for the following.

1. `InputQueue`
2. `OutputQueue`
3. Service Bus namespace connection string represented by `ServiceBusConnection`

**Update**

In case you need to move messages between two different namespaces, two connection strings are required and the code will look slightly different at the attributes level.

```
[FunctionName(nameof(PartStatusFunction))]
[return: ServiceBus("%OutputQueue%", Connection = "OutputServiceBusConnection")]
public Task<ServiceBusMessage> PartStatusFunction([ServiceBusTrigger("%InputQueue%", Connection = "InputServiceBusConnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
{
    logger.LogInformation("Sending message with ID {MessageId} to the destination queue", message.MessageId);

    return Task.FromResult(new ServiceBusMessage(message));
}
```

Note that this is going to work with In-Process SDK. For Isolated Worker SDK, the code will look slightly different but still follow the same idea.

Comment: But this way both the input and output service bus is the same right? I need to send the message to a service bus with another namespace connection string than the one that receives it.

Comment: You can do that as well. If your input and output queues are found in two different namespaces, remove `ServiceBusAccount` and supply the `Connection` argument for `ServiceBusTrigger` and  `ServiceBus` attributes. The Function code doesn't need to change.